# How to get request url in jsp in SpringMVC?

Tags: spring-mvc

I mapped page `/folder/hello.jsp` to controller `/hello` in Spring Mvc.

Now I want to get the controller mapped url `/hello` in my jsp by jstl `${pageContext.request.requestURL}`,but i get `/folder/hello.jsp`.

I tried `HttpServletRequest.getRequestURL()` in the controller and got the currect url that's I want to get.But I don't want to change my controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there is no Spring construct that will support this. In my view, its best to write an interceptor and add the mapping to a model attribute. Something as simple as

```
public class MapToModelInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, Object handler,
            ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {
         modelAndView.addObject("mapping", request.getRequestURI());
    }

    @Override
    public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, Exception ex)
            throws Exception {
    }

}
```

and the config

```
<interceptors>
    <interceptor>
        <mapping path="/**" />
        <beans:bean class="org.example.interceptors.MapToModelInterceptor"></beans:bean>
    </interceptor>
</interceptors>
```

Comment: Thanks,I soloved it by this way.